# PDO sql insert not executing and not showing error

Tags: php, sql, pdo

So this is my second project with PDO and after checking with my first project I can not for the life of me figure out why this INSERT is not working and I am not getting an error message. This is the firs time I am using PDO inside of sublime 3. Don't think this has anything to do with it just figured Id add that.

Here is my connection which is giving me no problems but here just in case!

```
<?php

$connString = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rmldb";
$uname = "root";
$pwd = "DB_PASS";

try{

$pdo = new PDO($connString, $uname, $pwd);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}catch(PDOException $e){

    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();

}?>
```

Here is my php with the query:
I checked to see if I was making it to the try/catch by adding an echo and I am getting all the way through to the end of the 'try' block but still nothing is being inserted and I cannot figure out why.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$formdata['fname'] = trim($_POST['fname']);
$formdata['lname'] = trim($_POST['lname']);
$formdata['email'] = trim($_POST['email']);
$formdata['pwd'] = trim($_POST['pwd']);
$formdata['pwd2'] = trim($_POST['pwd2']);
$formdata['phone'] = trim($_POST['phone']);
$formdata['date'] = $_POST['dateCreated'];


//Checking for empty form values
if(empty($formdata['fname'])){
    $err = 1;
    $errfname = "First name is required";
}
if(empty($formdata['lname'])){
    $err = 1;
    $errlname = "Last name is required";
}
if(empty($formdata['email'])){
    $err = 1;
    $erremail = "Email is required";
}
if(empty($formdata['pwd'])){
    $err = 1;
    $errpwd = "Please enter a password";
}
if(empty($formdata['pwd2'])){
    $err = 1;
    $errpwd2 = "Please enter a password";
}
if(empty($formdata['phone'])){
    $formdata['phone'] = "N/A";
}
//Checking for matching password values
if($formdata['pwd'] != $formdata['pwd2']){
    $err = 1;
    $errpwd = "Passwords do not match";
    $errpwd2 = "Passwords do not match";
}

//Checking for existing emails
try{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, email, pwd, phone, dateCreated, admin) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :email, :pwd, :phone, :dateCreated, :admin)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":fname", $formdata['fname']);
    $stmt->bindValue(":lname", $formdata['lname']);
    $stmt->bindValue(":email", $formdata['email']);
    $stmt->bindValue(":pwd", $formdata['pwd']);
    $stmt->bindValue(":phone", $formdata['phone']);
    $stmt->bindValue(":dateCreated", $rightnow);
    $stmt->bindValue(":admin", 0);
    $stmt->execute();
    $showform = 0;
    echo "<p class='error'> Recorded!</p>";
}catch(PDOException $e){
    $e->getMessage();
}
```

}

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Is `$rightnow` set?

Comment: I really think you should be using `else if`'s in your `if (empty())`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I know LOL I was testing the query before I moved on

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, $rightnow = date("M jS, Y"); this is set in the header.inc.php

Comment: Just a recommendation, don't write insecure code (even for "testing"). It's super easy to miss fixing some of those issues at a later point, which will result in an insecure application.

Comment: @JeanPaul98 Is there a benefit to using the elseif as compared to how I have it? Just cleaner code or something else?

Comment: @JeanPaul98 - This isn't an `elseif`-situation. The OP is checking different variables on each `if` and all of them needs to be checked.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Will do! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I didn't even read the whole code lol @MagnusEriksson but thanks for pointing it out and also is this your actual DB password? `$pwd = "";` I'd make an edit and change it to something like `$pwd = "DB_PASS";`

Comment: @JeanPaul98 Yes, that is the password

Comment: @Joe You never echo out the message. Change: $e->getMessage();
 to echo $e->getMessage();

Comment: @Jens Oh Geez... I didn’t even realize thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may not be the best way to do it but this should get you what you want.

```
<?php
    $formdata['fname'] = trim($_POST['fname']);
    $formdata['lname'] = trim($_POST['lname']);
    $formdata['email'] = trim($_POST['email']);
    $formdata['pwd'] = trim($_POST['pwd']);
    $formdata['pwd2'] = trim($_POST['pwd2']);
    $formdata['phone'] = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $formdata['date'] = $_POST['dateCreated'];

    //Checking for empty form values
    if (empty($formdata['fname'])) {
        $err = 1;
        $errfname = "First name is required";
    } else if (empty($formdata['lname'])) {
        $err = 1;
        $errlname = "Last name is required";
    } else if (empty($formdata['email'])) {
        $err = 1;
        $erremail = "Email is required";
    } else if (empty($formdata['pwd'])) {
        $err = 1;
        $errpwd = "Please enter a password";
    } else if (empty($formdata['pwd2'])) {
        $err = 1;
        $errpwd2 = "Please enter a password";
    } else if (empty($formdata['phone'])) {
        $formdata['phone'] = "N/A";
    } else if ($formdata['pwd'] != $formdata['pwd2']) {
         //Checking for matching password values
        $err = 1;
        $errpwd = "Passwords do not match";
        $errpwd2 = "Passwords do not match";
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, email, pwd, phone, dateCreated, admin) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :email, :pwd, :phone, :dateCreated, :admin)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(":fname", $formdata['fname']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":lname", $formdata['lname']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":email", $formdata['email']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":pwd", $formdata['pwd']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":phone", $formdata['phone']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":dateCreated", $rightnow);
        $stmt->bindValue(":admin", 0);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $showform = 0;
            echo "<p class='error'> Recorded!</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p class='error'> Sorry, there was an error!</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Still no luck. It will not even enter the else.

Comment: This helped!!! So the problem was in my database on phpmyadmin. I had the value for date created at length of 1 for some reason. When I changed the length, My original code started working! Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problemo and also I would suggest storing the date as varchar or text with a length of 11 or 255 (usually these are default values) @Joe

Comment: @JeanPaul98 You should suggest to store dates as it is in a date column, *not* as text or varchar